# How to store input values in JSON object using ng-model in Angular JS?

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to store the input values in JSON object and binding the JSON object to Span. its not working.
Direct ng-repeat is working, but if i bind it from JSON objeci its not working.

My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var JSONObject = {"name":"{{yourName}}"
        };
        document.getElementById("jname").innerHTML=JSONObject.name;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
      <p>
        Name: <span id="jname"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In header its working, in span i am binding from JSON its not working.
I tried in jsbin the same code its working.but if i create my own html its not working.

Help me.

Thanks in Advance,
Stephen.L

Comment: jsfiddle demo will be great, thanks!

Comment: @FUserThrowError [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/876xP/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Move your code to the end of the body. `document.getElementById("jname").innerHTML=JSONObject.name;` is executing before the span is added to the DOM...

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js">    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
      <p>
        Name: <span id="jname"></span>
      </p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var JSONObject = { "name":"{{yourName}}" };
        document.getElementById("jname").innerHTML=JSONObject.name;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JSBin... http://jsbin.com/qeseyibi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks @Anthony Chu ... One more help , I am using jsPdf to convert JSON object to PDF, in PDF i am not getting this JSON object. Example Code: var doc = new jsPDF();doc.text(10,20,JSON.stringify(JSONObject.name));

Comment: Should it be `JSON.stringify(JSONObject)`?